# does SoapClient run on UI thread just like WebClient?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7, soap, webclient

I have this confusion that makes me uncertain about the origin of performance lag in my Windows Phone 7 application.

We all know WebClient runs on UI thread and is evil and should be avoided. But I have a webservice which is reference using visual studio so a class like XXXSoapClient : ClientBase is generated for that. Now the question is:

"Is this running on UI thread as well?"

-- Assuming the answer is yes, what is the workaround? Calling complex webservice methods using URL and HttpWebRequest is so labour-intensive!

Cheers.

P.S. Good news is that from "Mango" issue with WebClient will be resolved and it will run on "Originating thread".

Comment: Don't know but I bet it does.

Comment: What does `ClientBase` use internally?

Comment: This is the signature of ClientBase<T> Class:
ClientBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject where TChannel : class

Comment: Assuming the answer is yes, what is the workaround? Calling complex webservice methods using URL and HttpWebRequest is so labour-intensive!

Answer (score 0):

WebClient will run on Originating Thread for Windows Phone 7.1/7.5